# AngularJS filter an array

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have the following ng-repeat:

```
<td data-ng-repeat="scheduleAbsenceDayContainer in scheduleAbsenceMonthContainer.scheduleAbsenceDayContainers track by $index
```

and **scheduleAbsenceDayContainer** can contain an array of **scheduleIntervalContainers**:

[image]

My question now would be if there is any possibility to filter all scheduleIntervalContainers with a special **containerType** value.
My filter- name is is calles **vm.absenceType**:

```
<select name="typeSelection" id="typeSelection" data-ng-model="vm.absenceType"
```

I have tried this one withour success, because I don't know how to gete any or when not possible only the first one:

```
<td data-ng-repeat="scheduleAbsenceDayContainer in scheduleAbsenceMonthContainer.scheduleAbsenceDayContainers track by $index | filter: {scheduleIntervalContainers(any or - when not possible than only first): {containerType.value: vm.absenceType}}"
```

Comment: Why not using a `ng-if="scheduleAbsenceDayContainer.scheduleIntervalContainers[0].containerType === vm.absenceType"` ?
you could add in this `ng-if` a `|| !vm.absenceType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use nested `ng-repeat`. Then you can use a custom filter to filter the scheduleIntervalContainers using your `vm.absenceType` model variable.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="scheduleAbsenceDayContainer in scheduleAbsenceMonthContainer.scheduleAbsenceDayContainers track by $index">
    <div data-ng-repeat="scheduleIntervalContainer in scheduleAbsenceDayContainer.scheduleIntervalContainers | filter: check" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Custom filter function

```
$scope.check = function(a){
    if (angular.equals(a.containerType,$scope.vm.absenceType))
        return true;
    else
        return false;                    
}
```

You could also implement this without a custom filter function by renaming your filter model (if it's possible) to vm.containerType and giving `filter : vm` in the nested ng-repeat.